# How to handle a heavy request on a server?

Tags: python, scaling, horizontal-scaling

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but, i am desperate for an answer.

The problem in hand here is not the number of requests but, the amount of time one single request will take. For each request, the server has to query about 12 different sources for data and it can take upto 6 hours for server to get the data (let's leave request timeout from this because, this is not the server directly communicating with the client. This server is fetching messages from kafka and then starts getting the data from the sources). I am supposed to come up with a scalable solution. Can anyone help me with this?

The problem don't end here:

- Once the server gets the data, he has to push to kafka for further computation using spark. Streaming api will be used in this part.

I am open to any web framework or any scaling solution in python.

Comment: Can you please provide what are the `sync` ans `aync` parts in the above mentioned requests

Comment: @Sarathsp this is another problem which needs to be solved. The query from different sources that the server will do have to go to a kafka cluster from where spark will consume the data and begin processing using the streaming api. If we run the queries parallely, then the problem will arise in kafka where the ordering will matter when there are multiple requests.

Comment: And, i should add this, i don't have experience with kafka. I just started learning.

Comment: You should look at maybe doing this with websockets. Stream the data to the user as it becomes available.

Comment: @EmettSpeer yeah. That's for the request to not timedout which i said is not a problem.

Comment: @VivekAnand You do realise that if you stream the data out over websockets then as your server gets the kafka messages you can update the users web interface. If you're not interested in that you may want to do some digging on why its taking 6 hours to run.

Comment: @VivekAnand look at serverless architecture, AWS Lambda is one example. It is scalable and your are freeing up your web server to handle web requests rather doing a batch job.